# Format of time like (hh:mm) in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, time, pipe, angular8

i want to display the time in (hh:mm). But date Pipes is not working for this

```
let transformTime=this.datePipe.transform(x.AllowedHrs,"hh:mm");
```

Comment: Is `x.AllowedHrs` a dateTime value?

Comment: have you tried to use `Moment` ?

Comment: x.AllowedHrs is time value

Answer (score 1):

You've got three ways of doing this (mainly):

1. You use Angular's built in date pipe: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

If you plan on displaying this information, in your HTML file where you would display:
`<p>{{ myDate }}</p>` you would replace this with `{{ myDate | date:"HH:mm" }}`
}

2. You create a custom pipe if you want to manipulate or change the time further:

https://angular.io/guide/pipes

3. You utilize the external library such as Moment.JS

https://momentjs.com/

Comment: {{ myDate | date:"HH:mm" }} this is not working in html because i want convert time in hours and minutes